# jQuery is not defined in bundle.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, webpack, hugo

I have been stuck on this issue for several days now and I have tried literally dozens of different fixes from my searches. To start, I am using Hugo, Webpack, Node.js, and Babel. Currently, everything is at least compiling, but when I look at the localhost console I see these errors:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at Object.609 (bundle.js:2)
    at n (bundle.js:2)
    at Object.83 (bundle.js:2)
    at n (bundle.js:2)
    at Module.150 (bundle.js:2)
    at n (bundle.js:2)
    at bundle.js:2
    at bundle.js:2
609 @ bundle.js:2
n @ bundle.js:2
83 @ bundle.js:2
n @ bundle.js:2
150 @ bundle.js:2
n @ bundle.js:2
(anonymous) @ bundle.js:2
(anonymous) @ bundle.js:2
localhost/:1 Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:1313/scss/node_modules/bootstrap-icons/font/bootstrap-icons.css' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
localhost/:1 Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:1313/node_modules/animate.css/source/animate.css' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
localhost/:1 Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:1313/home/elijah/GolandProjects/ReplayRLB/website/testsite1/assets/plugins/magnific-popup/magnific-popup.css' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
```

Now my main reasoning for the post is to solve the jQuery issue, but insight into the other issue would be great too, as I have also been stuck on it for a while as well.

### webpack.config.js

```js
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
// const WebpackManifestPlugin = require('webpack-manifest-plugin');

module.exports = {
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: ['babel-loader'],
            }
        ]
    },
    entry: './assets/js/script.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'assets', 'js'),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
    },
    externals: {
        jquery: 'jQuery',
    },
    /*    plugins: [
           new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: 'jquery',
            jQuery: 'jquery'
            })
        ]*/
};
```

My imports from script.js (aka main js file):

```js
app.use("/static", express.static('./static/'));
import $ from "../plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js";
import jQuery from "../plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js";
import "../plugins/@popperjs/core/lib/popper.js";
import "../plugins/google-map/map.js";
import "../plugins/magnific-popup/jquery.magnific-popup.min";
import Shuffle from "../plugins/shuffle/shuffle.min.js";
import "../plugins/slick/slick.min.js";
import lozad from "lozad";
//Pricing Scripts
import "../js/pricing/boosting.js";
import "../js/pricing/tourneyTitle.js";
import "../js/pricing/placements.js";
import "../js/pricing/coaching.js";
/* ========================================================================= */
/*  jQuery load initialize
/* ========================================================================= */

window.$ = require('../plugins/jquery/jquery.min');
window.jQuery = $;
require('./script.js');

/* ========================================================================= */
/*  shuffle load initialize
/* ========================================================================= */

const shuffleInstance = new Shuffle(document.getElementById('grid'), {
    itemSelector: '.js-item',
    sizer: '.js-shuffle-sizer',
});

/* ========================================================================= */
/*  lazy load initialize
/* ========================================================================= */

const observer = lozad(); // lazy loads elements with default selector as ".lozad"
observer.observe();
```

**Calling the bundle for my main source of js**

```html
<script src="./assets/js/bundle.js"></script>
```

Please note that this is NOT in static/assets as when I tried that it didn't work and gave me an error saying you cant send static files to the client or web(something along those lines). My assets dir is the equivalent of a src directory I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "jQuery not defined" error should generally mean your not loading the jQuery library.
Your trying to use ES6 Import syntax I guess?

1. `import { $, jQuery } from 'jquery';` type statements depend on what jQuery version you are using, please check that (I can't tell what version of jQuery you are pulling), also the jQuery import seems a bit different? See above import statement.
2. To keep it simple, you can also test for a traditional jQuery import statement a la:
   `<script type="text/javascript" src="https:// CDN LINK HERE "></script> and see if` you can get basic jQuery statements working in console.

I'm sorry my English isn't the best, but the above might assist in debugging.

Do let me know.

Comment: I ended up just using the cdn in my head.html and it works. Now I am having other issues that I will probably post about though. Like Style is not defined in bundle.js. I think it has somethign to do with my imports in my scss, It could also be from this error: Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:1313/node_modules/animate.css/source/animate.css' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

Comment: Like how do I change the mime type of a freaking plugin.

Comment: Please, if you open a new question, I'll see if I can assist. I'll watch out for it. Best of luck, yes?

Comment: I already did! just click on my name and you should see it :)

Answer (score 0):

I am getting this error.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

So to fix it, in my **main.js**(some name it as **entry.js**) I had added this line.

```
global.jQuery = global.$ = require('jquery');
```

And the **webpack.config.js** is as follows.

```js
const path = require('path');

var $ = require('jquery');

let config = {
  entry: ['./main', './node_modules/jquery', './node_modules/jquery-validation', './node_modules/jquery-validation-unobtrusive', './node_modules/bootstrap'],
  output: {
     publicPath: "/js/",
     path: path.join(__dirname, '/wwwroot/js/'),
     filename: 'main.build.js'
  },
}
 
module.exports = config;
```